Upgrade XSD to Java translation from Java 8/JAXB to Java 17/Jakarta
I am struggling to update an existing Java 8 and JAXB Gradle build that generates Java objects from an XSD to Java 17 and Jakarta. How would I update the following Gradle task to use Jakarta? Is there an XJC Jakarta task? I can't seem to find a reference to one.
Here is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'compileJava'

project.ext {
    jaxbTargetDir = "xsd_src"
    schemaSrc = "xsd_v1.0"
    schemaName = "schema_20180419.xsd"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        // use ant generated src and extra source
        java { 
            srcDir "${jaxbTargetDir}"
            srcDir 'extra_src'
        }
        // include the src in the jar
        resources {
            srcDir "${schemaSrc}"
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.fork = true  // Fork your compilation into a child process
    options.forkOptions.setMemoryMaximumSize("4g") // Set maximum memory to 4g
}

configurations {
    xsd2Java
}

dependencies {      
    // Java EE Dependencies
    xsd2Java('jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0')
    xsd2Java('jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.0.0')
    xsd2Java('jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.0-B1')
    
    implementation 'org.javassist:javassist:3.29.0-GA'
    
    // Versioning comes from Maven Jaxb2 Plugin   
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb2-basics:2.0.5'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb2-basics-ant:2.0.5'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-basics-annotate:2.0.5'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb2-basics-runtime:2.0.5'
                
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.0-M4'
    
    compileOnly 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.28'
}

task xsd2Java() {
    doLast {          
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.xjc.XJC2Task', classpath: configurations.compileClasspath.asPath)
        ant.jaxbTargetDir = file("${jaxbTargetDir}")

        ant.xjc(
            extension: true,
            destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}',
            binding: file("${schemaSrc}/bindingsv.xjb"),
            
        ) {
            schema(dir: "${schemaSrc}") {
                include(name: "${schemaName}")
            }
            arg(line: "-nv -extension -xmlschema -Xannotate -XtoString -Xequals -XhashCode -Xcopyable")
            // check the timestamps on xsds and java files to see if we need to regenerate
            depends(dir: "${schemaSrc}") {
                include(name: "**/*.xsd")
            }
            produces(dir: "${jaxbTargetDir}") {
                include(name: "**/*.java")
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn 'xsd2Java'

I've also updated the bindingsv.xjb to reference Jakarta:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd 
                    http://annox.dev.java.net"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc" version="3.0">

However when I run the build I get this error:
Execution failed for task ':Services:messages:xsd2Java'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

How can I solve this error?

Checking my own notes I made during the upgrade from Spring Boot 2.2 to 3.2 (which also required upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17), I explicitly kept the namespace for xjc as xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" in the jaxb bindings file.  Maybe try that? I never found any evidence that the namespace should be changed and in fact this document seems to indicate it should stay the same: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/docs/ch05.html#jaxb-ri-extensions-xjc-customizations

I don't know if that would totally solve your problem but you're using jaxb2-basics v2 with jakarta build, which is unsupported.
You should migrate to v4 version (4.0.8 latest at this moment). See migration guide on how to go from v2 to v3 (and then from v3 to v4) here
    // Versioning comes from Maven Jaxb2 Plugin, replaced by v4 equivalent in same order
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins:4.0.8'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-ant:4.0.8'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugin-annotate:4.0.8'
    implementation 'org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-plugins-runtime:4.0.8'


That fixed it! Thank you!

Nice :) Glad it helped you
